# How to resolve constraint violation error when loading data from CSV to PostgreSQL using Spark and JDBC?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, jdbc

I have a project in which I am reading a CSV file from Amazon S3 and performing data processing using Spark. I then create a DataFrame and load it to a PostgreSQL database via JDBC. However, I'm getting a constraint violation error because the `customernumber` column in the `customerlocation` table is unique.

What I need is for the Spark job to read the CSV file, process it, and then append the data to the PostgreSQL table. If a duplicate key is found in the `customernumber` column, I want it to be ignored and the non-duplicate records to be inserted without failing the Spark job.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Customerlocations(
            LOCATIONID INT,
            CUSTOMERNUMBER INT,
            CUSTOMERCOUNTRY VARCHAR(50),
            CUSTOMERSTATE VARCHAR(50),
            CUSTOMERDISTRICT VARCHAR(50),
            CUSTOMERCITY VARCHAR(50),
            SERIALNO VARCHAR(50),
            CORPID VARCHAR(50),
            INDATE TIMESTAMP,
            CUSTOMERMOB2 BIGINT,
            DISTRIID INT,
            unique (CUSTOMERNUMBER)
            );
```

this is my table structure and have same columns dataframe in spark, i want to write this dataframe to jdbc but whenever the customernumber violation error occur i have to do nothing and insert remaining rows so that i am writing like this

```
customerlocationDF.write \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbcurl) \
    .option("dbtable", "customerlocations") \
    .option("user", properties_local['user']) \
    .option("password", properties_local['password']) \
    .option("batchsize", "5000") \
    .option("rewriteBatchedStatements", "true") \
    .option("driver", properties_local['driver']) \
    .option("numPartitions", "10") \
    .option("saveMode", "Append") \
    .option("batchsize", "1000") \
    .option("truncate", "false") \
    .option("ignoreDuplicateKeys", "true") \
    .option("upsertBatchSize", "1000") \
    .option("upsertKeyCols", "customernumber") \
    .option("rewriteBatchedStatements", "true") \
    .option("insertStatement", "INSERT INTO customerlocations (LOCATIONID, CUSTOMERNUMBER, CUSTOMERCOUNTRY, CUSTOMERSTATE, CUSTOMERDISTRICT, CUSTOMERCITY, SERIALNO, CORPID, INDATE, CUSTOMERMOB2, DISTRIID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ON CONFLICT (CUSTOMERNUMBER) DO NOTHING") \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

It throwing error of

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 3)
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO customerlocations ("locationid","customernumber","customercountry","customerstate","customerdistrict","customercity","serialno","corpid","indate","customermob2","distriid") VALUES (22183512,26327538,'INDIA','MAHARASHTRA','PARBHANI','PARBHANI','L-B6BC2AF58C',NULL,'2023-01-01 05:32:07+05:30'::timestamp,NULL,0) was aborted: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "customerlocations_customernumber_key"
  Detail: Key (customernumber)=(26327538) already exists.  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
```

Can anyone suggest a solution or a workaround for this issue?

Comment: `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`

Comment: @Laurenz Albe how to write this in spark jdbc. beacuse its thorwing error when i used this

Comment: If you cannot get Spark to do it, use JDBC directly. Don't use `rewriteBatchedStatements`, write a multi-line `INSERT` directly and add the `ON CONFLICT` clause.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe Thank you for your suggestion, I'm fairly new to this and was wondering if you could provide a more detailed explanation or perhaps an example of how to do this?